# No se porque el código de Tkinter no funciona

Tags: python, tkinter

Lo que quiero es que aparece una pequeña interface de tkinter el código es sencillo pero no le encuentro el por que no me funciona.
El código es este:

```
from tkinter import *
import winsound 


Freq=37
Freq_est=0
Dur=0



def cam_label(Symbol, Pm):

    global Freq
    global Dur
    global Freq_est
    if Symbol=="-" and Pm=="Freq":
        Freq-=1
        Freq_est-=1
    elif Symbol=="-" and Pm=="Dur":
        Dur-=1
    elif Symbol=="+" and Pm=="Freq":
        Freq+=1
        Freq_est-=1
    elif Symbol=="+" and Pm=="Dur":
        Dur+=1
    winsound.Beep(Freq, Dur)


root=Tk()

MyFrame=Frame(root)
MyFrame.pack()

LabelFreq=Label(MyFrame, text=Freq_est)
LabelFreq.grid(row=2, column=2)


LabelDur=Label(MyFrame, text=Dur)
LabelDur.grid(row=4, column=2)


BFreqx=Button(MyFrame, text=">", command=cam_label("+", "Freq"))
BFreqx.grid(row=2, column=3)

BFreqi=Button(MyFrame, text="<", command=cam_label("-", "Freq"))
BFreqi.grid(row=2, column=1)

BDurx=Button(MyFrame, text=">", command=cam_label("+", "Dur"))
BDurx.grid(row=4, column=3)

BDuri=Button(MyFrame, text="<", command=cam_label("-", "Dur"))
BDuri.grid(row=4, column=1)

LabelWFrecuencia=Label(MyFrame, text="Frecuencia: ")
LabelWFrecuencia.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)

LabelWDuracion=Label(MyFrame, text="Duracion: ")
LabelWDuracion.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

lo que intento es que cuando le des a un botón incremente o decremente la frecuencia o a duración y suene.

Información variables:
la frecuencia debe ser mayor que 37 y menor que 32767
·Así que he hecho una frecuencia (Freq) y una frecuencia que debe mostrar (Freq_est)
·dur corresponde a la duración

Comment: Especifica el error con mas detalles. Necesitamos saber si lanza una excepción o es un error de lógica.

Comment: No funciona ni suena ni suma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siento haber molestado preguntando, pero ya no es necesario que respondan pues conseguí hacer que el código funcionase.

Solución:

```
from tkinter import *
import winsound 

Freq=37
Freq_ste=0
dur_ste=1
dur=dur_ste*1000


def Sonidos(frecuencia, duracion):
    winsound.Beep(frecuencia, duracion)
    

def Reset():
    global Freq
    global Freq_ste
    global dur_ste
    global dur
    Freq=37
    Freq_ste=0
    dur_ste=1
    dur=dur_ste*1000
    LFF.config(text=Freq_ste)
    LDD.config(text=dur_ste)
def Fi():
    global Freq
    global Freq_ste

    if Freq>=47:
        Freq-=10
        Freq_ste-=10
        LFF.config(text=Freq_ste)

def Fx():
    global Freq
    global Freq_ste

    if Freq<=32757:
        Freq+=10
        Freq_ste+=10
        LFF.config(text=Freq_ste)

def Fii():
    global Freq
    global Freq_ste

    if Freq>=87:
        Freq-=50
        Freq_ste-=50
        LFF.config(text=Freq_ste)

def Fxx():
    global Freq
    global Freq_ste

    if Freq<=32717:
        Freq+=50
        Freq_ste+=50
        LFF.config(text=Freq_ste)
def Di():
    global dur
    global dur_ste
    if dur>=2000:
        dur_ste-=1
        dur=dur_ste*1000
        LDD.config(text=dur_ste)
def Dx():
    global dur
    global dur_ste
    if dur<=4000:
        dur_ste+=1
        dur=dur_ste*1000
        LDD.config(text=dur_ste)

root=Tk()

MyFrame=Frame(root)
MyFrame.pack()

LFrec=Label(MyFrame, text="Frecuencia: ")
LFrec.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=3)

LDur=Label(MyFrame, text="Duración: ")
LDur.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=3)

LFF=Label(MyFrame, text=Freq_ste)
LFF.grid(row=2, column=3)

LDD=Label(MyFrame, text=dur_ste)
LDD.grid(row=4, column=3)


BxF=Button(MyFrame, text=">", command=Fx)
BxF.grid(row=2, column=4)

BiF=Button(MyFrame, text="<", command=Fi)
BiF.grid(row=2, column=2)

BxxF=Button(MyFrame, text=">>", command=Fxx)
BxxF.grid(row=2, column=5)

BiiF=Button(MyFrame, text="<<", command=Fii)
BiiF.grid(row=2, column=1)

BxD=Button(MyFrame, text=">", command=Dx)
BxD.grid(row=4, column=4)

BiD=Button(MyFrame, text="<", command=Di)
BiD.grid(row=4, column=2)

Oir=Button(root, text="Oir sonido", command=lambda:Sonidos(Freq, dur))
Oir.pack()

resetear=Button(root, text="Reset", command=Reset)
resetear.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

El error se encontraba en que había que "actualizar" el Label así
`LabelDeEjemplo.config(text=Variable)`
también le añadí unos botones que sumasen la frecuencia de 50 en 50, ahora en vez de una función hay varias y una botón que lo resetea todo.

Podéis probar el código y ponerlo agudo, esta bien si queréis tener dolor de cabeza